Multivariate Taylor Series equals iterated univariate Taylor Series
I am asking myself wether the following fact is true:
Let $f(x_1,\ldots,x_k) \colon U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a multivariate function.
Do the multivariate Taylor series $$MT_{f}(x_1,\ldots,x_k) = \sum_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^k} \frac{\partial^\alpha f(0,\ldots,0)}{\alpha!~\partial x^\alpha} x^\alpha \qquad \text{where $\alpha$ is used as a multi-index}$$
and iterating univariate Taylor series expansion (i.e. treating the other variables as constants)
$$
\begin{align*}
T_{f}(x_1,\ldots, x_k) &= \sum_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}} \frac{\partial^\alpha f(0,x_2,\ldots,x_k)}{\alpha!~\partial{x_1^\alpha}} x_1^\alpha\\
T_{T_{f}}(x_1,\ldots,x_k) &= \sum_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}} \frac{\partial^\alpha T_{f}(x_1,0,\ldots,x_k)}{\alpha!~\partial{x_2^\alpha}} x_2^\alpha\\
&\;\vdots\\
IT_{f}(x_1, \ldots, x_k)&= \sum_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}} \frac{\partial^\alpha T_{T_{\ddots_{T_{f}}}}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,0)}{\alpha!~\partial{x_k^\alpha}} x_k^\alpha
\end{align*}
$$
coincide? Specifically:

if the multivariate Taylor series $MT$ does not exist, the iterated one $IT$ also does not exist
if they both exist, they are equal and the iteration method is invariant under variable permutation, e.g., the sequences $x_1\to x_2\to x_3\to \ldots \to x_k$ and $x_2 \to x_1 \to x_k \to \ldots$ should result in the same Taylor series.


Factorials are missing here.

What is $U$ here? What do you mean by "series [...] does not exist"? Exist in what sense?

@Iosif For example for $f(x,y) = \frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^2}$ the first iteration yields $T_f(x,y) = 0 + yx - \frac{6}{y} x^3 + \frac{120}{y^3} x^5 ...$. Then the second iteration $T_{T_f}(x,y)$ does not exist as the first derivative of $\frac{-6}{y} x^3$ with respect to $y$ at $y=0$ does not exist hence we cannot construct the second iteration as described in the above scheme.

Your "For example" comment does not answer my questions.

We would surely want to assume at the very least that $f\in C^{\infty}$ near zero, and then the two methods obviously produce the same formal object. Convergence is a separate issue of course.

@Iosif: I am sorry that I am somehow not able to answer your questions precisely. I think my issue really is about points where the actual function f is not defined. So for my example comment, U would be all points where the denominator does not become zero. However I „still want to develop a Taylor series at this singularity“ and I thought this might lead into problems, that the expressions above are not well-defined anymore.

@ChristianRemling most likely I do not understand the topic in enough detail, but why is it „obvious“? My issue is, that in the iterated version substitutions occur in sequence whereas in in the multivariate setting they happen simultaneously. So for $\frac{x}{y}$ the simultaneous substitution with zero is not defined, the one where I do y first also not but the one where I first set x to zero works. Couldn’t this lead to an issue?

@WaveL: That doesn't matter here since (for differentiable functions, which your example is not) $\partial f(x,y)/\partial x$ at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is the same whether you first take the derivative and then set $x=y=0$ or first fix $y=0$, differentiate the resulting function of $x$ and finally take $x=0$.
